# How to Save (SubmitChanges) When TwoWay Binding to a Database

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 app (Silverlight) that has a page with a textbox that is bound (TwoWay) to a property on the viewmodel which gets the value from a Linq to Sql database. It all works except when I change the value of the textbox, it sets everything correctly but does not call the SubmitChanges of the datacontext and therefore does not get saved. Is this a normal scenario? Should I do it differently? Is there a way to tell two-way binding that it has to call the SubmitChanges method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't bind a text-box directly to a database. So if you're not using a ViewModel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but instead bind directly to a linq2sql entity class, you're doing it wrong.

Wrap the properties you wish to expose to the UI in a ViewModel, and call `SubmitChanges()` in your `PropertyChanged` event handler.

Of course, the best approach is to have a "natural saving point", such as if you have a page-change (like for OneNote/Office), or a Save Button.

Comment: Thanks! I do have a VM in between, so that sounds like a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. If you want to commit every time a property is changed, you can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of your object, and manually call `SubmitChanges`.

But I would not recommend it. For optimal performance, override the `OnNavigatedFrom` method of your page and call `SubmitChanges` there.